# Problem with Web Scrapping Stable Diffusion Web UI

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, stable-diffusion

Hi I want to change the sampling steps, height, and width
[The UI of the Stable Diffusion Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xInix.png)

I have checked the class name for the sampling step and I copied it to the selenium
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHXQW.png)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get(site)

time.sleep(1)

sampling_steps = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "gr-box gr-input gr-text-input text-center h-6")
sampling_steps.send_keys("80")
```

Then I got error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".gr-box gr-input gr-text-input text-center h-6"}

Is there a way to fix this problem? (I have tried XPATH but it didn't work)

I have tried using XPATH, and I have searched stack overflow for moving the range but popped out the same error: no such element

Comment: I would put smaller code in code blocks as well (This helps readability). For example: `code` (auto formatted into block) vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't support compound class names, i.e. class names with spaces.

You can search by *CSS selector* instead. Class names are represented slightly different in CSS. In this case, you'd want

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gr-box.gr-input.gr-text-input.text-center.h-6")
```

Though there might be more optimal ways for this specific case. See [locator strategies](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) in the documentation.

Comment: Still same error: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".gr-box.gr-input.gr-text-input.text-center.h-6"}

Comment: @Will Depending on the site you are loading, the element might very well be inside an _iframe_ If that's the case, follow this [guide](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

Comment: I have tried this, but it also popped out the same error

iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#modal > iframe")

oh by the way, the link of the site is this: http://127.0.0.1:7860
however, if I don't run the webui.bat in the stable-diffusion folder, the site won't be loaded

Comment: @Will Try `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")` It is odd that they give the other one as a first example, because that is a very specific selector.

Comment: Code:
`iframe = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

sampling_steps = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gr-box.gr-input.gr-text-input.text-center.h-6")
sampling_steps.send_keys("80")`

Result:
`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"iframe"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=110.0.5481.104)`
Still the same

Comment: @Will It might be that the DOM is not fully loaded yet. You should use a better suited [waiting mechanism](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).

Comment: I have tried using implicitly_wait for 15 seconds, but the result is still the same. Then just to make sure I changed it to 60 seconds, still no luck